# How to change the url?

Tags: url-rewriting

How to rewrite the url in wordpress?

Instead of http://yapkimyks.com/product-list/astarlar/

it should be http://yapkimyks.com/product-list/yapbond/astarlar/

where,

yapbond is main category name

astarlar is sub category of yapbond

Comment: You should be able to achieve it from under permalink settings in wp admin of your website.

Comment: I already set the custom permalinks structure like :/%category%/%postname%/ @sri

Comment: Are you using regular categories? Or a custom taxonomy of a similar name? You will need to reflect that in your permalinks structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Categories' hierarchy in URL](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178139/categories-hierarchy-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mention is that post or page.
If it is page. than you can check this plugin [Custom Permalink Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/).
I am not sure but this plugin may help you.