# Subcategory Page 404ing

Tags: categories, permalinks, 404-error, seo

I am having an issue with Subcategory pages 404ing.

Desired URL hierarchy:

- Blog = `/blog`
- Category = `/blog/CAT`
- Subcategory = `/blog/CAT/SUBCAT`
- Post w/ Category as primary = `/blog/CAT/POST`
- Post w/ Subcategory as primary = `/blog/CAT/SUBCAT/POST`

Settings:

- Blog page is set to be `/blog`
- Permalink structure = `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`
- Category base = `empty`
- Yoast SEO “Remove the categories prefix” = `Remove`

Everything else is working, but the Subcategory pages are 404ing. And the actual URL that is successfully loading for the Subcategory pages is `/CAT/SUBCAT` — but this is not what is linked in the sitemap or on the blog posts which are in a subcategory.

I have tried a few different combos of settings, but not successful yet. How can I resolve this issue?

--

Unfortunately this gentleman who had [the same issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209886/404-error-on-subcategory-pages) did not ultimately resolve the Subcat page 404 issue

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178139/categories-hierarchy-in-url and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088721/wordpress-category-hierarchy

Comment: Bikash — both of those questions relate to the Cat / Subcat showing up in a Post. My issue is related to the Subcat page itself not resolving correctly.